# Javascript Array doesn't work in constructor Poo

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

I try to push data into a javascript Array in my constructor and got this error :

```
TypeError: this.listeetudiant is undefined
```

This is my constructor :

```
function Cours(){

*/the array that doesnt work : */
this.listeetudiant=[]; 

*/ the method that is supposed to use the content of the array and to add data to   the     array */
this.affForm=printForm; 

}
```

then, i try to add datas to listeetudiant using the method, but it doesn't work :

```
function printForm(){
 this.listeetudiant.push = (1);
}
```

and I try

```
this.listeetudiant.push(etudiant[id].id);
```

where etudiant[id].id is a correct var...

But it still doesn't work and says     TypeError: this.listeetudiant is undefined.

PLease Help me !

It works well when there is only one data to add to one unique variable.
But it doesn't work at all with arrays ! 
I need to push several datas into my array listeetudiant, at various periods of time and it doesn't work at all.

For exemple if i write :

```
function printForm(){
this.listeetudiant=(1); 
alert(this.listeetudiant);
}
```

it works well, and listeetudiant value becomes 1 into my object.
the problem is that i don't want to add one value, i want listeetudiant to be an array and to be able to add 30 values ! Snif !

Comment: Were are you calling `this.listeetudiant.push = (1);`? It probably has to do with the fact that wherever you are, `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: I really really hope that `etudiant[id].id` equals `id`...

Comment: Can you show us some runnable Javascript that demonstrates this happening, because something in your description of this problem doesn't add up.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's into a Jquery droppable function, but i can't publish my code there, it would be not understandable. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Youve never actually defined `this.listeetudiant`. You have created a constructor but you never actually call the constructor so  `this.listeetudiant` has yet to be defined.
If Cours is supposed to be an object it you need to call it first:

```
var cours = new Cours();
```

then you could do something like `cours.listeetudiant.push();`

```
function printForm(){
 this.listeetudiant.push = (1);
}
```

-- the `this` in this case is the printform function. The `this` in the cours function means the cours function. `this` refers to the scope of whatever you are in. listeetudiant is an array which is an attribute of the cours object so when you want to push to that array you need to reference the object to which it belongs when you call it.

Comment: yes Sorry I've changed a few the content of my answer, for you to understand better. Sorry i'm a foreign. Thank a lot for your help

Comment: Even with the edited answer you still dont call your constructor.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but in my complete code, i've called the constructor like how you said var cours = new Cours(); It even works with MONO VARIABLES but Not with ARRAYS. I dont understand why.

Comment: then when you want to push something to the array in cours you call `cours.listeetudiant.push(thing_you_want_to_push)` which is calling the array of the object and pushing to that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you all of you Jack and

Thanks a lot for your help, finally... Made it work like that :
    function printForm(){
    cours.listeetudiant.push('1','12'); 
    }

Just for information, It was an array of objects so i 've done it like that :
    cours[0].listeetudiant.push('1','12');

Have a nice day from France.
I'll help if one day i'm able to.

If u wanna see what i'm working on code: http://nicolashcodes.wordpress.com/2014/09/29/exercice-19-supercours-logiciel-sur-tablette-android-daffectation-deleves-a-un-cours-par-drag-and-drop/

I don't know how to close a problem ?

Comment: if youre happy with an answer you can click on the arrow under it to accept it.